# How to print dataset content using Rexx

Tags: rexx

I'm trying to print the data (line by line) found in the IO.ME.DATA dataset (see my jcl).

I get the following error and looking to get the syntax right:

```
10 +++  DO I = 1 TO SYSTSIN.0
Error running MYREXX, line 10: Bad arithmetic conversion
```

I'm new to REXX. Thanks

JCL

```
//JCL01  JOB 000,'TEST REXX',
//             CLASS=T,
//             MSGCLASS=X,
//             USER=ME
/*JOBPARM R=999,T=999,L=9999,S=ANY
//*
//STEPREXX EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,PARM='MYREXX'
//SYSEXEC  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=IO.ME.REXX
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTSIN  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=IO.ME.DATA
//
```

MYREXX (IO.ME.REXX)

```
SAY 'START OF REXX CODE.'

"EXECIO * DISKR SYSTSIN (STEM LINE. FINIS"

DO I = 1 TO SYSTSIN.0
  SAY "VALUE OF I : " SYSTSIN.I
END

SAY 'END OF REXX CODE.'
```

DATA (from IO.ME.DATA)

```
MYDATA1,A
MYDATA2,B
MYDATA3,C 
MYDATA4,D
MYDATA5,E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the do loop to

```
DO I = 1 TO Line.0
  SAY "VALUE OF I : " Line.I
END
```

the command

```
"EXECIO * DISKR SYSTSIN (STEM LINE. FINIS"
```

says read the file **SYSTSIN**  in to the stem variable **Line**. The number of lines read will be placed into **line.0**, **line.1** will hold the first line in the file etc.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Bruce Martin wrote, don't point `SYSTSIN` to your input data.  Use a different DD.  `IKJEFT01` uses `SYSTSIN` for its own purposes.  Even if it works *in this particular case*, it's a bad habit to use DDNAMES that are known to be used for other purposes for your own.

```
//JCL01  JOB 000,'TEST REXX',
//             CLASS=T,
//             MSGCLASS=X,
//             USER=ME
/*JOBPARM R=999,T=999,L=9999,S=ANY
//*
//STEPREXX EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,PARM='MYREXX'
//SYSEXEC  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=IO.ME.REXX
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSTSIN  DD DUMMY
//MYDATA   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=IO.ME.DATA
//*
```

This wasn't going to fit in a comment, but I felt it important to point out.